# Task.WhenAll recursion inconsistent results compared to for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, recursion

I have a method where I need recursion to get a hierarchy of files and folders from an API (graph). When I do my recursion inside of a for loop it works as expected and returns a hierarchy with 665 files. This takes about a minute though because it only fetches one folder at a time, whereas doing it with Task.WhenAll only takes 10 seconds.

When using Task.WhenAll I get inconsistent results though, it will return the hierarchy with anywhere from 661 to 665 files depending on the run, with the exact same code. i'm using the variable totalFileCount as an indication of how many files it has found.

Obviously i'm doing something wrong but I can't quite figure out what. Any help is greatly appreciated!

For loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count; i++)
{
    var folder = folders[i];
    await GetSharePointHierarchy(folder, folderItem, $"{outPath}{folder.Name}\\");
}
```

[image: For loop runs]

Task.WhenAll

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count; i++)
{
    var folder = folders[i];
    var task = GetSharePointHierarchy(folder, folderItem, $"{outPath}{folder.Name}\\");
    tasks.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

[image: Task.WhenAll Runs]

Full method

```
public async Task<GraphFolderItem> GetSharePointHierarchy(DriveItem currentDrive, GraphFolderItem parentFolderItem, string outPath = "")
{
    IEnumerable<DriveItem> children = await graphHandler.GetFolderChildren(sourceSharepointId, currentDrive.Id);
    
    var folders = new List<DriveItem>();
    var files = new List<DriveItem>();

    var graphFolderItems = new List<GraphFolderItem>();
    foreach (var item in children)
    {
        if (item.Folder != null) 
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(outPath + item.Name);
            //Console.WriteLine(outPath + item.Name);
            folders.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            totalFileCount++;
            files.Add(item);
        }
    }

    var folderItem = new GraphFolderItem
    {
        SourceFolder = currentDrive,
        ItemChildren = files,
        FolderChildren = graphFolderItems,
        DownloadPath = outPath
    };

    parentFolderItem.FolderChildren.Add(folderItem);


    for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count; i++)
    {
        var folder = folders[i];
        await GetSharePointHierarchy(folder, folderItem, $"{outPath}{folder.Name}\\");
    }

    return parentFolderItem;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have a race condition with your totalFileCount++,  try using Interlocked.Increment(ref totalFileCount);

Comment: Aside from the totalFileCount race condition, you will also have issues with the folderItem.FolderChildren collection from the folderItem instance passed in `var task = GetSharePointHierarchy(folder, folderItem, $"{outPath}{folder.Name}\\")`, unless you specifically chose a thread-safe collection type for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is race condition problem. In parallel execution, you should not use normal datatype or variable. You should always use thread safe concept as per your requirement like [thread safe datatypes/collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/)  or [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) or [Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter?view=net-6.0) or [interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-6.0).

In this case, interlocked.Increment is good approach like replace the below one where using `totalFileCount`

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref totalFileCount);
```

Please refer the below link for good understanding

[Thread Safe concept in details](https://www.learncsharptutorial.com/thready-safely-csharp.php) or [Thread-safety](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1c8574/thread-safety369/)

Answer (score 1):

It seemed like the problem is when you are using the **Task.WhenAll** way you are making **the code flow run in parallel** and in the other way with **await** each time you run the async function, **the code flow is actually not run in parallel**

and this is exactly your problem, your source code inside the async function access to shared memory object - totalFileCount
What causing **multi threads access to an object at the same time.**

For fixing it and still execute the code in parallel, surround the access to totalFileCount instance with the lock statement which limit the number of concurrent executions of a block of code

```
lock(lockRefObject) 
{ 
    totalFileCount++;
}
```

Comment: you are right, I corrected the misleading phrase